# Dynamics 365 9.x. Global context property of the form context. Supported?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365-v9

While debugging web resources in Dynamics crm 9.0 I found that Form context always has a property `context` that is a reference to a global context.

The provided global context is fully functional and very useful especially in home page ribbons.

Why such important property `formContext.context` is not listed/ documented in Microsoft topics and articles? 
Is it supported?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Undocumented is unsupported.

The previous equivalent `Xrm.Page.context` is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/xrm-utility/getglobalcontext) now.

> getGlobalContext method provides access to the global context without going through the form context. It contains an equivalent of all the methods available for the Xrm.Page.context object (now deprecated) to retrieve information specific to the client, organization or user.

To get the global context in supported way, use `Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext()`, this will return the same expected `formContext.context`.

Who knows when & where `formContext.context` will break (like UCI) or get changed in future, but MS will give you through `Xrm.Utility`